# Enable 1 input field inside a disabled fieldset with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, fieldset

I've searched for other similar questions, but they're not the same with what I want to do.

```
<fieldset disabled>
    <input id="input1"/>
    ...
    <input id="input2"/>
<fieldset>
```

When the fieldset is disabled, I need "input2" to still be enabled.  Is there anyway to do this with pure Javascript.  No framework such as JQuery please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the fieldset, which doesn't disable the items, so you will then need to find the items in the fieldset except for `#input2` and disable them.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.disabled input:not(#input2)')
  .forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = true
  })
```

```html
<fieldset class="disabled">
  <input id="input1" />
  <input id="input2" />
</fieldset>
```